# How to set a custome name in Java RS json response for simple list type

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, jersey-2.0

if entity is just a List tokenList
then this line

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(tokenList).build();
```

will return

> {     "ArrayList": [      "c2171488"  ] }

if I change to

```
GenericEntity entity = new GenericEntity<List<String>>(tokenList) {}
```

I got

> {     "List": [       "c2171488"  ] }

all I want is to change the name in the JSON response to be "token", so it should look like

> {     "Token": [      "c2171488"  ] }

Is there a simple way to do it?

ResponseBuilder entity function has a variant with Annoation, howevery there is no example that I can find.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#entity-java.lang.Object-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-

Answer (score 1):

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
       .entity(Collections.singletonMap("Token", tokenList).build()
```

Comment: thanks, now it returns {
 "SingletonMap": {
  "Token": []
 }
}

Comment: have you done any custom configuration on the default object mapper? Default serializer will not create json like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution

String results = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Collections.singletonMap("Token", tokenIdList));
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(results).build();